# Ubuntu 19.04 Wifi not working on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme gen 2

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, 19.04, thinkpad

I just install Ubuntu 19.04 today as dual boot but wifi is not recognized. My laptop is Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2. I did some checks on terminal

EDIT: updated kernel to 5.1.1 and also tried updating iwlwifi from the post tagged by @chilly555 but both aren't working.

```
lspci | grep -i network
52:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)

iwconfig
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

lspci -vnn | grep Network
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 10
       serial: 48:2a:e3:51:f8:30
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:150 memory:cf800000-cf81ffff

sudo rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE                   SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth tpacpi_bluetooth_sw unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0                unblocked unblocked
```

EDIT: updated kernel to 5.1.1 and also tried updating iwlwifi from the post tagged by @chilly555 but both aren't working.

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.098882] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    3.098883] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8042:654c426c
[    3.125180] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.158857] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    3.158978] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159073] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159163] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159172] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159180] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159191] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159199] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159310] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159322] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159329] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159336] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159460] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159470] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159477] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.159478] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    3.159507] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-cc-a0-39
[    3.159535] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-cc-a0-52
[    3.159564] iwlwifi 0000:52:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

EDIT: Found the final solution by download the file from Intel and copy it to /lib/firmware to solve last problem.